# Starting external .exe when XPS Writer has finished

Tags: printing, driver, xps, print-spooler-api, v4-printer-driver

I wrote a XPS Driver using the  XPS Driver Sample [XPS Driver Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/print/XPSDrvSmpl)
What I want to do now is, that I need to start an external programm when the XPS Driver has finished its job and the document is ready.
So the user should click "print with... -> myCustomXPSDriver..." and after the xps document is ready a program should start.
My problem is, that I can't get the job status and dont know how to get the information that the document is ready without watching the directory.
I need the driver for Windows 10, so I can't use a port monitor.
Any examples and/or ideas which is the right way to do this?

-Printer Extension?
-Universal Windows Application?
-BIDI Extension?

Thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: Hey, perhaps not so useful, but you can always use a V3 driver in Windows 10, which supports port monitors. Alternatively, the property bags in filters have a user token that can be used to impersonate the user. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/print-pipeline-property-bag. Perhaps this could be used to spawn a user scoped process? (Note, I'm not sure if this is advised against by Microsoft. I think I read somewhere that filters shouldn't spawn new processes, but I can't quite remember.)

Comment: Add on to the above, it's just a recommendation: 

"The following recommendations apply to filters:

Filters should not create separate processes or threads. If a separate process or thread is required, the filter must properly manage the process or thread lifetime." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/implementing-xps-filters